# How do I build a kernel image using Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, kernel, osdev, multiboot

I'd like to build an embedded kernel for an x86 machine using Visual C++.  I have some C and assembly code files to compile and I'd like to link them all together in a way that is compatible with a Multiboot bootloader like GRUB.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to go down the MSVC path? It's a great compiler but I think this would be much easier with GCC/MingW

Comment: I think GCC/MinGW will generate PE executables as well.  I'll have to make the necessary changes for ELF to PE in either environment.  VS is just such a pleasure to use, I think I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OSDev has a [wiki entry on Visual Studio](http://wiki.osdev.org/Visual_Studio), that may provide some insight, especially with the links to Kaushik Srenevasan's [blog](http://ksrenevasan.blogspot.com/2005/10/writing-multiboot-pe-kernels-using.html) [entries](http://ksrenevasan.blogspot.com/2005/10/writing-multiboot-pe-kernels-using_03.html) on the subject of PE kernels designed to be loaded by multiboot-based bootloaders (like GRUB).

A couple of large, broad-strokes things you should know:

- In the multiboot header, you need to use the AOUT kludge.
- You need to specify the /BASE:0x100000 argument to the linker, so the final binary code is based to where the bootloader is going to put it.
- Your kernel's entry point (usually called '`kmain`') needs to have `__declspec(noreturn)` on it, and you will need to do an `__asm { hlt }` instead of returning.

Comment: Copy-and-paste doesn't work here, either, but points to the mistake: it looks like "...kernels-using%5F03.html", but should be "...kernels-using_03.html".

Comment: I don't know why, but I'm copy & pasting it from the address bar into here, and it has a literal '_' when I edit -- SO seems to be replacing it for whatever reason.

Comment: Ok, I sent an email to the SO Team, and they pointed out that there are other ways to make a link, so I switched it to one that works.